# How to open incognito window in JMeter Webdriver sampler

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

I want to open the incognito window in JMeter Webdriver sampler.Following is my code.How to open incognito browser?

```
var pkg=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium) //import java selenium package
var support_ui=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait) //import WebDriverWait Package
var ui=JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui) //import Selenium Support UI package
var wait=new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,180)
```

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart() //sample starting point
    WDS.browser.get('${__P(application.url)}')
    wait.until(ui.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.id('pmj-login-btns')))
    WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible without modifying the JPGC_ChromeDriverConfig plugin code. Atleast, I am not aware of it.

But, there is an option to use JSR223. Please check the below code:-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized")
options.addArguments("--incognito");

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Path\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
```

Above will launch the browser in incognito and maximized mode.

Hope this help.